# why array_filter dont working?

Tags: php, arrays

i need to use the date() in $var like this:

```
$array = array(1 => '2017-10-05', 'February', 'March');

function month($var) {
$date = date('Y-m'); 

return (stripos($var, $date) !== false); 
}

$filtered = array_filter($array, 'month');

var_dump($filtered);
```

I do not understand why it returns an empty array
but when I write it like that, it works:

```
$array = array(1 => '2017-10-05', 'February', 'March');
print_r(array_filter($array, function ($var) { return (stripos($var, '2017-10') !== false); }));
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you need to assign `function ($var) {` to a variable and pass it to array_filter, or you need to give your function a name:  `function checkDate($var) {`.

```
function checkDate($var) {
    $date = date('Y-m'); 
    return (stripos($var, $date) !== false); 
}

$filtered = array_filter($array, 'checkDate');
```

Or

```
$checkDate = function ($var) {
    $date = date('Y-m'); 
    return (stripos($var, $date) !== false); 
}

$filtered = array_filter($array, $checkDate);
```

Comment: Yes, just forget to write, thanks, however, the problem continues

Comment: Also, $date needs to be in scope within the closure

Comment: @MetaCode Your code works for me with the updated solution. Maybe your timezone or Clock are incorrect and date('Y-M') is not the day you think it is?  php -f test.php 
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2017-10-05"
}

Comment: One more question, what can this error mean? `stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in` I have this problem with another array

Comment: The first argument must be a single value, not an array of values.

Comment: then how can I filter this? `array(1) {
  [258]=>
  array(9) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-07"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-07"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-07"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-13"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-13"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-13"
    }`

Comment: array_filter accepts an array, and runs the callback for each item in the array.  If you have nested arrays, you need to do a recursive call.  Ex:  `function checkDate($var) {  
    $response = false;
    if (is_array($var) { foreach ($var as $item) $response = checkDate($var); } 
    else {
    $date = date('Y-m'); 
    $response = (stripos($var, $date) !== false); 
} return $response;

$filtered = array_filter($array, 'checkDate');`

Comment: I am missing the closing `}` after return $response; but you will figure it out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157696/discussion-between-meta-code-and-alex-barker).

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(1=> '2017-10-05', 'February', 'March');

function date_func($var){
  return (stripos($var, date('Y-m')) !== false); 
}

var_dump(array_filter($array, 'date_func'));
```

https://eval.in/888623

In case you're not planning on reusing the function you should call it within the filter like so

```
$array = array(1=> '2017-10-05', 'February', 'March');

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v){
    return (stripos($v, date('Y-m')) !== false); 
});
```

Results are the same:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2017-10-05
)
```